# SUPEE Patches Don't Support Magento versions: 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4?

Tags: magento-1.7

I noticed that SUPEE 8788 excluded magento 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4 versions. I though Magento will support 1.x versions for the next 2-3 years.
 Why did they stop releasing SECURITY patches for 1.x lower versions?

Comment: you must seriously avoid 1.2,1.3 and 1.4 version if you are using still.

Comment: I understand that they are old but still.... I thought that when they say 1.X are supported  for 2 years after magento 2 came out, I assume they are supported.. now it looks like they ditched all versions below 1.5

Answer (score 1):

No one provides updates for an obsolete code base. This is no different than Microsoft providing patches for 3.1. Update, quickly.